# Viability of creating a wireless LAN bridge between mobiles and PCs using a portable router?

Tags: electrical-engineering, software, telecommunication

I am creating a network to share files between a mobile device and multiple PCs directly through a LAN. The purpose of which is to use smart phones to capture files from remote devices which are outside the range of the internet.

The current plan is to use a portable router that could be brought on site and act as a bridge between the mobile client and the PCs to allow for the passing of the desired files.

I am new to LAN and router network and have had issues when trying to use the router as a bridge as so I was wondering if it would be better to create the network with the device in router, repeater and bridge modes? What would be the reasons for this? Or is there a better way to create a network?

NOTE: for this application the mobile device needs to be able to talk to multiple PCs at one time so WiFi direct is not a valid option. And there is nowhere on site to leave a permanent router which is why a portable router is a suggested option.

Comment: This is a standard feature, easily implemented in some devices, and essentially not at all in others which have the capability but not the programmed functionality. My terminology is not 'up with the play ' here and others will give terminologically superior answers. Essentially you are implementing an access point. - anything that includes that term in its description should do what you want. Other devices are intended to extend the range of 'WiFi' systems ('repeaters') and also work. What may give problems are modem routers or even just routers that in some cases seen to go out of their ....

Comment: .... way to not allow ready LAN extension. | A useful 'trick' can be to use any cell phone that has both WiFi LAN access and simultaneous access point generation. Some will do only one or other at a time. Such a device can be used for LAN access and then provide a separate sub LAN with its own SSID and so separate logins. A  'not in most books' trick for wireless LAN range extension is to run an insulated wire from near the main WiFi source to near the receiver. This removs the trie 'wireless'capability (almost) but allows now contact aqcess in radio deadspots. I am using a Spark Core ....

Comment: .... (now Particle) IOT device (ARM Cortex with ARduino brain and TI 802.11x module) in a deep dungeon without enough signal. An insulated wire wraps (literally) around the main Wifi router and ends in physical but non-electrical-contact proximity with the IOT device and provides good access.

Comment: What operating systems are installed in the PC's? I configured a similar configuration. The step are document in the question [Configuring a Wired Access Point - Linksys WRT54G](http://superuser.com/questions/757973/configuring-a-wired-access-point-linksys-wrt54g/762439#762439)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thanks for your detailed response. The end system is going to deployed in numerous parts around the world and so we have to design a system that will work on multiple different Android mobiles (without assured WiFi LAN and access point generation) and also iPhone devices (particularly popular in America). The idea I am currently exploring is having a portable router that the phone can also join WiFi network. I am likely coming across the issue you mentioned that the router is going out of its way not to allow proper LAN extension so might just be a product choice issue.

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena PCs are running a combination of Windows 7 and Windows XP. There WiFi is connected by OTS WiFi dongles.

Comment: Although your question is okay, maybe it is a little bit offtopic to a low-level engineering site. I would suggest to try for example, http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com , with similar questions - with the exception if your problem is essentially a low-level, hardware-near one.